# Structured Maven profiles in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

We have a company-created Maven plugin that requires many (40+) defined profiles.

All those profiles are alphabetically listed in the Profiles folder in the Maven tab in IntelliJ IDEA.

Is it possible to create subfolders in the Profiles folder?

Instead of seeing:

```
V Profiles
  [ ] profile_one
  [ ] profile_two
  [ ] profile_three
      :
  [ ] profile_forty
```

I'd like to have:

```
V Profiles
  > Profile_subfolder_A
  V Profile_subfolder_B
    [ ] profile_five
    [ ] profile_six
  > Profile_subfolder_C
      :
```

Comment: Why do you need so many profiles? What is the purpose of them? We are talking about a maven plugin?

Comment: Each profile has a unique set of configuration settings for the plugin. The number of profiles keeps growing over time.

Comment: I didn't know about similar way to configure it. I could suggest you to try something like this one - https://medium.com/@keybinApp/configuration-as-a-service-caas-rest-api-and-webhooks-673eaa3b38c7 Otherwise your pom will be unreadable soon

Comment: Within a single project you have 40 different configuration settings for a single plugin? can you give some examples what kind of configuration is needed and what for?

Comment: If you use more than 40 profiles it is likely that there is a much simpler solution that you overlooked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such groupping in IDE. There are related request you can vote for:
[IDEA-142807](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-142807), [IDEA-81772](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-81772).